# Unhashing a string

Tags: javascript, hash

I tried by myself to unhash a string that was hashed using the following function

```
    function hashCode(a) {
      var b, c, d = 0;
      if (0 == a.length) return d;
      for (b = 0, l = a.length; l > b; b++) c = a.charCodeAt(b), d = (d << 5) - d + c, d |= 0;
      return d
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible to create reverse function to get the unHashed string?

Comment: Hashes aren’t really reversible. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm making a plugin in goodbarber application for a customer and there is a list (Favorite items) that are stored in localStorage in web (while developing) but in mobile devices use another storage solution (when deployed). The problem is that I can set directly the key and value to the localStorage but for devices, I need to know the key name to load / save the favorite items.

Comment: Why do you use the hash as key name? What is this *other storage solution*?

Comment: the key name is for retrieving the value from the storage. This goodbarber is a framework that allows user to create hybrid apps. I now that developing in web, it uses localStorage as "User Defaults", but I don't know what it use when app is being executed in mobile device.

Comment: So you mean that this *goodbarber* thing itself creates this hash?

Comment: yeap! using the function posted above

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is one way.. Incase if you want to check or validate, you can use the same salt in the other end to hash and check if both the values are equal.